# 2 domains pointing to 1 server (2 different subfolders)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, domain-name, a-records

OK, so, I think the title is rather self-explanatory.

I've set up my own Apache server (on Debian) and hosting 2 different sites (let's say `mysite1.com` at `/home/www/mysite1`, and `mysite2.com` at `/home/www/mysite2`).

In my domain name registrar setup page (Dynadot actually), I created **A records** (still not sure what this is exactly...) for both of them, pointing to my server's ip...

Now, on the server's side, here'e what my .conf file looks like (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite` actually)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite1.com
    ServerName www.mysite1.com
    ServerAdmin drkameleon@gmail.com

    <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/www/mysite1.com>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin

    <Directory "/home/www/mysite1.com/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/phpmyadmin
    ServerName www.mysite1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite2.com
    ServerName www.mysite2.com
    ServerAdmin drkameleon@gmail.com

    <Directory />
         Options FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/www/mysite2.com>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the thing is. Now matter which site I visit (1 or 2), I always get `mysite1`'s contents.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have any CNAME records setup for site2 do you?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities of what could go wrong.

Do you have

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

somewhere in the config? (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)

Without that config entry Apache is not sensitive to domain names in dispatching requests to virtual hosts.

It's just a guess.

Make sure Apache has been reloaded after any changes to the config!

Comment: Hmm... I've tried putting that in the config files, before (`apache2.conf` or the `mysite` conf file under `/sites/enabled` and then restarted apache (`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`). However, it keeps saying : `Restarting web server: apache2apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Wed Jan 29 17:05:01 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`. Why is that?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon that is just a warning but it won't keep apache from starting. Check This,http://aslamnajeebdeen.com/blog/how-to-fix-apache-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-using-127011-for-servername-error-on-ubuntu

Comment: Hmmm. Just did that as well. First, the warning stays there. As for the rest of it, I didn't say Apache didn't restart. It does. The thing is I'm still having 2 domains pointing to the exact same location... :-S

Comment: Just to make sure - you are visiting http://www.mysite1.com and http://www.mysite2.com? NOT, by any chance, http://mysite1.com and http://mysite2.com? The latter will not work with this configuration.